# Mapping an array to a new array with default values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, default-value

I have an array of start times and stop times for a stopwatch. I need to turn them into one final array that is the actual amount of time that passed for each entry. I always need the length of the final array to be 4, so if there are fewer than 4 `times` entries, I need a `0` to be in the final array in that place. The amount of input entries will always be 4 or less.

**Example input:**

```
[
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 },
  { startTime: 2345, stopTime: 7432 },
  { startTime: 4567, stopTime: 6252 }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[ 1111, 5852, 5087, 1685 ]
```

However, if there are fewer than 4 entries, I want them to be `0` instead.

**Example Input:**

```
[
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[ 1111, 5852, 0, 0 ]
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
var times = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
]

function getTimes (arr) {
  var output = arr.map(function (interval) {
    return interval.stopTime - interval.startTime
  })

  return output
}

console.log(getTimes(times))
```

Right now, this doesn't do anything to make sure that the array is a length of 4 with the extra 0's added on. I know that one thing I could do is something like this:

```
while (output.length < 4) {
  output.push(0)
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this rather than adding this after the `map`.

Comment: I believe I mentioned above: "The amount of input entries will always be 4 or less"

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is utilizing `Array.prototype.map()` as follows;

```js
var durations = [{ startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
                 { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 },
                 { startTime: 2345, stopTime: 7432 },
                 { startTime: 4567, stopTime: 6252 }
                ],
          res = new Array(4).fill();
res = res.map((e,i) => durations[i] ? durations[i].stopTime - durations[i].startTime : 0);
console.log(res);
```

And on a second thought; i think i would in fact do this job with a for of loop as follow;

```js
var durations = [{ startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
                 { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 },
                 { startTime: 2345, stopTime: 7432 },
                 { startTime: 4567, stopTime: 6252 }
                ],
          res = new Array(4).fill(0),
            i = 0;
for (var duration of durations) res[i++] = duration.stopTime - duration.startTime;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat()` to append on as many additional zeros as you need:

```
return output.concat([0,0,0,0].slice(arr.length));
```

Working example:

```js
var times = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
]

function getTimes (arr) {
  var output = arr
      .map(function (interval) {
          return interval.stopTime - interval.startTime
      })
      .concat([0,0,0,0].slice(arr.length))

  return output
}

console.log(getTimes(times))
```

If you wanted to abstract out the desired number of entries (e.g. using 6 below), you could store that number in a variable and use that to dynamically build the filler array:

```js
var times = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
]

var numEntries = 6
var fill = new Array(numEntries).fill(0)

function getTimes (arr) {
  var output = arr
      .map(function (interval) {
          return interval.stopTime - interval.startTime
      })
      .concat(fill.slice(arr.length))

  return output
}

console.log(getTimes(times))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is absolutely fine. But if you want an alternative, instead of your loop you can push the missing entries into the array:

```
output.push.apply(output, [0, 0, 0, 0].slice(0, 4 - output.length));
```

or in ES2015+

```
output.push(...[0, 0, 0, 0].slice(0, 4 - output.length));
```

That pushes the missing `0`s onto your existing `output` array.

```js
var times = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
];

function getTimes (arr) {
  var output = arr.map(function (interval) {
    return interval.stopTime - interval.startTime
  });
  output.push.apply(output, [0, 0, 0, 0].slice(0, 4 - output.length));

  return output;
}

console.log(getTimes(times));
```

But frankly, I'd stick with the loop. If this is something that comes up a lot for you, you might have a utility function you use for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a new array with the wanted length and use a default value for non existent Items.

```js
var times = [{ startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 }, { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }];

function getTimes (arr, len) {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: len }).map(function (_, i) {
        return arr[i] ? arr[i].stopTime - arr[i].startTime : 0;
    });
}

console.log(getTimes(times, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to return array if `.length` of resulting accumulated array is equal to variable or input parameter `Number`, else utilize `Array.prototype.fill()`, spread element to fill remaining indexes up to variable

```
var checkTimes = (times, len) => {
  var res = times.reduce((arr, obj) => [...arr, obj.stopTime - obj.startTime], []);
  return res.length < len ? [...res, ...Array(len - res.length).fill(0)] : res;
};
```

```js
var times1 = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 },
  { startTime: 2345, stopTime: 7432 },
  { startTime: 4567, stopTime: 6252 }
];

var times2 = [
  { startTime: 1234, stopTime: 2345 },
  { startTime: 3452, stopTime: 9304 }
];

var checkTimes = (times, len) => {
  var res = times.reduce((arr, obj) => [...arr, obj.stopTime - obj.startTime]
            , []);
  return res.length < len ? [...res, ...Array(len - res.length).fill(0)] : res;
  };

console.log(checkTimes(times1, 4), checkTimes(times2, 4))
```